# Rotating point object so that it is perpendicular to line on other layer in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, rotate

I need to Rotate point object so that it is perpendicular to line on other layer.

need to line up valve symbol(points) perpendicular with the underlying watermains (polyline)

on ArcGis Pro

Comment: Buffer valve by 1m, intersect buffer with pipes. Add geometry attributes to small segments, bearing. Transfer it back to valve table using valve id. Go-to symbol properties and add 90 to it in rotation dialogue.

Comment: sorry bit a novice with arcgis pro,dont fully understand where does the bearing come from? also after you buffer you join between the mains and valves to bring the geometry across to the valve buffer layer?